# Callback authentication with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, http, authentication

Is it possible to use HttpClient with callback authentication so we can prompt the user to enter credentials if the authentication fails?

Comment: Have you looked at [Authentication Guide](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/authentication.html)? And maybe [AuthenticationStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/AuthenticationStrategy.html)